# undefined local variable or method `current_user' cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a login/logout system. Instead of using devise, I created an active records User model and use sessions to remember if a user is logged in. Everything was working fine until I added these lines in the `application_controller.rb` to have a layout before login and one after.

```
layout :set_layout
  def set_layout
    if session[:current_user_id]
      'afterlogin'
    else
      'application'
    end
  end
```

Now, after I log in and `cancancan` is being used somewhere in a html page I get `undefined local variable or method 'current_user'`. I think that I have to add a `current_user` method but I'm not exactly where and how to define it.

Edit: I already had something similar in another class that is being used by login:

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authorize

  def authorize
  begin
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:current_user_id]) if session[:current_user_id]
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    session.destroy
    redirect_to '/login',alert: 'Please login'
  end
end

end
```

Should I modify this after I add that method ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CanCanCan expects a current_user method to exist in the controller. 
First, set up some authentication (such as Authlogic or Devise). 
See Changing Defaults if you need different behavior.
```

I would suggest you to install Devise so that it comes with a complimentary current_user method.

FYI: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

---

UPDATE

when a user logins successfully, you can store the user's id in session.

```
session[:current_user_id]=user.id
```

so that, in your applicationcontroller, you can do

```
 def current_user
    @current_user ||= session[:current_user_id] && User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id]) 
 end
 helper_method :current_user
```

Comment: I don't want to use devise. I want to use what I created which was working until the change of layouts(if I remove it it's working fine). I read the documentation, I asked what to put in that method in my case. This is not an answer.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel Since the current_user method is defined in the ApplicationController, I will just call the current_user method in the begin block.

Comment: shouldn't I add 'redirect to login' somewhere ?

Comment: ```begin
    current_user
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to '/login',alert: 'Please login'
  end```

Comment: Thank you so much :D. I really appreciate all of your help.

Comment: glad that it helps :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104756/discussion-between-jefferson-choi-and-bogdan-daniel).